# Как проверить откуда было обновлено состояние?

Tags: reactjs

Написал код, который должен обновить состояние 1 раз, но где-то что-то обновляет его ещё раз сразу же после первого раза. Можно ли как-то получить Stack-Trace при обновлении состояния в React, чтобы посмотреть, что его обновляет?

Comment: выведите console.log состояния в местах его изменения и смотрите что происходит при загрузке странице, если состояние хранится в redux, то есть прагин для браузера, там можно посмотреть  вызываемые события и все изменения store по ним. Скорее всего состояние обновляется несколько раз из-за лишних рендеров, которые не было запланированы, это можно решить установкой условий для смены состояний только в определенные моменты

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите узнать краткий фрагмент без каких-либо внешних зависимостей, то можно пойти простым путём, через метод `componentDidUpdate` вывести информацию:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  Object.entries(this.props).forEach(([key, val]) =>
    prevProps[key] !== val && console.log(`Prop '${key}' changed`)
  );
  Object.entries(this.state).forEach(([key, val]) =>
    prevState[key] !== val && console.log(`State '${key}' changed`)
  );
}
```

> [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) - вызывается сразу после обновления. Не
>   вызывается при первом рендере. Метод позволяет работать с DOM при обновлении компонента.

Еще можно заюзать небольшой хук, для отслеживания обновлений функций компонентов:

```
function useTraceUpdate(props) {
  const prev = useRef(props);
  useEffect(() => {
    const changedProps = Object.entries(props).reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => {
      // если значение изменилось - вернем его в результирующем объекте
      if (prev.current[key] !== value) {
        accumulator[key] = [prev.current[key], value];
      }
      return accumulator;
    }, {});
    if (Object.keys(changedProps).length > 0) {
      console.log('Changed props:', changedProps);
    }
    prev.current = props;
  });
}

// Использование
function MyComponent(props) {
  useTraceUpdate(props);
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

Дополнения к коду:

> Хук эффекта [`useEffect`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) даёт вам возможность выполнять побочные
>   эффекты в функциональном компоненте. Хук `useEffect` представляет собой
>   совокупность методов `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, и
>   `componentWillUnmount`.
>
> [`useRef`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) возвращает изменяемый ref-объект, свойство `.current`
>   которого инициализируется переданным аргументом (`initialValue`).
>   Возвращённый объект будет сохраняться в течение всего времени жизни
>   компонента.
>
> Метод [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) применяет функцию reducer к каждому элементу
>   массива (слева-направо), возвращая одно результирующее значение.
>   `accumulator` - значение, которое возвращает функция `callback` после
>   посещения очередного элемента, либо значение `initialValue`, если оно
>   предоставлено

Ссылка на источник: [Trace why a React component is re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51082563/5275890). Думаю, что этого будет достаточно, чтобы отследить изменения. Также, можно поставить брэйкпоинт (`debugger;`) и посмотреть по стэку вызовов в браузере, откуда растут ноги.

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста комментарии к вашему коду (во втором примере) а то имя переменных состоит из одной буквы и очень сложно догадаться что они делают.

Comment: @Demon__ANT простите, а что именно не понятно? Вы про метод `reduce` и аргументы колбэка внутри него?

Comment: Про все что внутри хука `useEffect`

Comment: Есть пакет https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-did-you-update, который делает примерно то же самое из коробки

Comment: @DenisBubnov спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот набор библиотек/компонентов/техник, которые решают вашу проблему https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#component-update-monitoring

Особо выделю https://github.com/reactopt/reactopt

Comment: Было бы неплохо показать чуть более подробно как это будет решать. На текущий момент выглядит не как полноценный ответ, а как некоторое общее указание в какой стороне искать способ решения проблемы. Обратите внимание: поле ответ предназначено для исчерпывающих и полных ответов, у вас же пока скорее хороший комментарий.

Comment: ну, тут нет конкретного ответа, без примера кода от @JamesJGoodwin, кто-то меняет props/state и происходит перерисовка ;)